# ajax datatable laravel Linking

Tags: ajax, laravel, datatable, routes, slugify

I have a datatable using yajrabox package with links to various strings. When I click on a link, it takes me to a 404 page with "/teams/"string". How do I make this string a viewable page? I have tried using a slug, but I could be using it incorrectly and honestly I don't know where my error is. Here is the impt. parts of my code:

Route:

```
Route::get('/teams/display/{$slug}', 'TeamsController@display');
```

TeamsController:

```
public function display($slug)
{
    $teamdatas = LoserData::findBySlugOrFail($slug);



    return view('teams/display', compact('teamdatas'));

}
```

DataTable.blade

```
      {data: 'homeTeam', name: 'homeTeam', "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
        $(nTd).html("<a href=/teams/display/"+oData.homeTeam+">"+oData.homeTeam+"</a>");
        }},
```

teams/display.blade.php

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <h1> Welcome the {{$teamdatas->slug}} profile page</h1>



    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your route is `teams/display/{slug}` not `teams/{slug}`, thus `teams/string` will throw a 404, it should be `teams/display/string`

Comment: thanks, I referenced the docs and got it to work, but this comment sparked the investigation so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I should have checked the routing docs because it was definitely a routing issue. To solve it put this in your routes:

```
Route::get('/teams/display/{teamdatas?}', 'TeamsController@display', function ($teamdatas = 'Oilers-84') {

return $teamdatas;
```

});

Here is the info from the Laravel Docs 5.5:

Optional Parameters
Occasionally you may need to specify a route parameter, but make the presence of that route parameter optional. You may do so by placing a ? mark after the parameter name. Make sure to give the route's corresponding variable a default value:

```
Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = null) {
    return $name;
});

Route::get('user/{name?}', function ($name = 'John') {
    return $name;
});
```